# Selecting id against each field in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a list of ids as (1,2,3...)

i called it $category_ids. Now in the same table there is a field of super_parent_category which means the highest label of that category in list.

Now i want to retrieve super parent ids for each of the category ids.

```
SELECT es_super_parent,es_id 
       FROM ephpb2b_categories 
       WHERE es_id IN ({$category_ids})");
```

The above query is returning me only 4 records as all of the ids in $category_ids belongs to these 4 categories.

But i want a result of all 50 records that are in $category_ids.

So if i am supplying 1,2,4,5,6,6,76,
I should return 1,3,4,5,6,66,2,

Thanks

Comment: problem is that it is just return each parent category one time.. so if there are ids in (3,4,5) and they are belong to one parent_category i.e 7. so it is returning 7 only 1 time

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean. Is $category_ids coming from a (sub)query? If so, can you post it? And schemata of both tables.

Comment: Its a single table. actually its a table of categories.


the primary key is es_id and in the same table there is a column parent_cateogry_id.

Now its a single table containing categories and subcategories. The category whose super_parent_id is not equal to 0 is a sub category

Comment: @user3445065 - see my answer, please. Works for me. If I misunderstood you, please elaborate a bit more in detail. Can't see a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Double check your PHP variable `$category_ids` with a `var_dump()`, i.e.

I testet it with your provided sample data.

```
SELECT es_super_parent, es_id 
    FROM ephpb2b_categories 
    WHERE es_id IN (1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 6, 76);
```

and the following table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE ephpb2b_categories (
    es_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    es_super_parent INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (es_super_parent) REFERENCES ephpb2b_categories (es_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And inserted some data:

```
INSERT INTO ephpb2b_categories (es_id, es_super_parent) VALUES
    (0, 0),
    (1, 1),
    (76, 76),
    (2, 76),
    (3, 2),
    (4, 4),
    (5, 5),
    (6, 6),
    (66, 6);
```

Here's a working **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2e897b/1)**

Comment: He does not have enough reputation to do so :)